# Пакет android.support

Tags: android-sdk, android, eclipse

Подскажите, где взять пакет android.support, установлены SDK API 7, 14, 15, при этом eclipse во время компиляции одного проекта ругается на отсутствие данного пакета (по крайней мере, в указанных SDK его нет).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос снят: [Downloading the Support Package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html#Downloading).